# Git merge ignore blank lines

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am attempting to Git merge between two different repositories.  Theoretically they very similar but different practices on both have resulted in numerous whitespace differences in almost every file.

I can get the results I expect with "git diff -w -ignore-blank-lines" which does show only the files where there are genuine differences.  However, Git merge does not have the same options and "git merge -Xignore-space-change" still results in thousands of whitespace only differences.

The repositories have 40 folders and almost 20k files so I'm keen to have an accurate and automated way of merging them as this process will be repeated.

I also can configure a merge tool to ignore such changes but the process is still quite slow.  Ideally I'd use a "git merge -w -ignore-blank-lines" but this does not seem to be possible.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you've got genuine difference from `git diff` is not from `ignore-space-change`, it's from `-w` and it's equivalent to `-Xignore-all-space`.

So try `git merge -Xignore-all-space`, but it might be a better idea to review the difference before finishing the merge because ignoring all space option sometimes create wrong indentation.

Comment: Thanks for that but I have tried -Xignore-all-space and it still finds lots of differences.  Some are indentation differences with spaces or tabs and some are blank lines.  It's not too hard to identify the real differences between the files and deal with them,  I'd just like to be able to merge and ignore the blanks.